# Error in Rowspan when Iterating with handle bars

Tags: javascript, arrays, handlebars.js, frontend

I have a loop that covers the dynamic data requested through the handlebars.

```
<tr class = "">
             <td class = "fw-900" colspan = "2"> Salary </ td>
             <td class = "fw-900" colspan = "2"> Duties </ td>
             <td class = "fw-900" colspan = "1"> Name </ td>
         </ tr>

{{#each this.peoples}}
             <tr>
                 <td class = "text-uppercase" colspan = "2"> {{this.salary}} </ td>
                 <td class = "text-uppercase" colspan = "2"> duties </ td>
                 <td class = "text-uppercase"> {{this.name}} </ td>
                 <td class = "text-uppercase text-center total" rowspan = "{{../ members.length}}" colspan = "" width = "15%"> {{../ members.length}} </ td>
             </ tr>
{{/ each}}
```

When it renders the total, I would like to do a rowspan, but since the rowspan interaction also covers that rowspan line, what happens is that it will render one column to each rendered row.

How to carry out this strategy correctly?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, I ran into this problem myself. I solved this by getting the index of the current iteration of the each, then using a helper to check whether the index was 0 - the first iteration. If it is, then it renders the rowspanned td.

JS

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('conditionalHelper', function(lValue, rValue, options) {
  if (lValue == rValue) {
    return options.fn(this);
  }
  return options.inverse(this);
});
```

Template

```
{{#each this.peoples as | person personKey|}}
  {{#conditionalHelper personKey 0}}
    <td class = "text-uppercase text-center total" rowspan = "{{../ person.members.length}}" colspan = "" width = "15%"> {{../ person.members.length}} </ td>
  {{/conditionalHelper}}
{{/each}}
```

More information on the index functionality can be found in the docs [here](https://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html#block-params).